# locked records progress4gl

Tags: progress-database

I have a query that runs from the sql engine in a progress DB. My problem is when a table or a record is locked from the progress4gl engine, I can't access it from sql engine and the query returns nothing for that lock. 
Is there any way to access those rows or tables from a query in sql?

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching and i found one solution for this problem, the only one thing that i do was put "WITH (NOLOCK)" at the end of the query, something like this:
"SELECT * FROM table1 WITH (NOLOCK)", with that statement the query is able to read the rows locked.

I hope i was clear and that this can be useful for someone

Regards